# Notification at DART lang - Chrome Packaged App

Tags: dart, google-chrome-app

I want to use notification in Chrome Packaged app, built by DART.

my pubspec.yaml is:

```
dependencies:
    browser: any
    chrome: any
transformers:
    - chrome
```

my main.dart is:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:chrome/chrome_app.dart' as chrome;

void main() {
   ....
     NotificationOptions notOptions = {
       'message':  'this is a notification message'

     };

chrome.notifications.create('id1', notOptions).then((id) => print('notification created'));
....
}
```

it gave me a problem: "Undefined class 'NotificationOptions'"

if I removed the "as chrome" in the line importing the package, then I'm getting an error at  chrome.notifications.create(...) tilling that 'chrome' is undefined.

what mistake I made here, and what is the correct way to define the options for chrome notifications!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `as chrome` in the import you have to prefix references to identifiers in this package with `chrome`.

This is not valid Dart syntax

```dart
 NotificationOptions notOptions = {
   'message':  'this is a notification message'

 };
```

maybe it should be something like

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:chrome/chrome_app.dart' as chrome;

void main() {
 .....
     chrome.NotificationOptions notOptions = new chrome.NotificationOptions(type: chrome.TemplateType.BASIC,
    iconUrl:'/icon.png',title:'notification title', message:  'this is a notification message');

  chrome.notifications.create('id1', notOptions).then((id) => print('notification created'));
  ....
}
```

also the manifiest.json should include permission, as:

```dart
  "permissions": ["notifications"],
```

Comment: The error in DART editor disappeared, but got this error while execution: "Exception: Unsupported operation: 'chrome.notifications' is not available" at DARTIUM, I thought may be this is as I did not packafe the app yet, so packaged it and run it at Chrome after using dart2js, but the notification did not appear!!

Comment: Did you specify permissions? see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/notifications/manifest.json for an example. Can you please verify what `chrome.notifications.getPermissionLevel.then(print);` returns.

Comment: It was missing, I added the below line but nothing changed: "permissions": ["notifications"],

Comment: What about `getPermissionLevel`?

Comment: the chrome.notifications.getPermissionLevel.then(print); gave me an error at .then, telling: the method 'then' is not defined for the class 'Function'

Comment: Can you try `chrome.notifications.getPermissionLevel().then(print)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60401/discussion-between-hasan-a-yousef-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Thanks @Gunter for your time and support in Chat, I updated your answer, to reflect final statements worked with me.