# Notification at DART lang - html / browser / webkit / Desktop

Tags: dart, dart-html

I want to ask about the normal notification in DART, which is different than the Chrome Packaged App discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596250/notification-at-dart-lang-chrome-packaged-app)

I created the below code, the browser [DARTIUM] asked for permission as expected, but the response in both cases (Allow/Deny) appeared as "default" in the console, and the notification did not appear.

{

```dart
 void main() {
    Notification.requestPermission().then((String permission) {
     print(permission);   // ==> This is always = "default" for both Allow and Deny
   if (permission == "default") {
       print('permission granted');
       var notification = new Notification('hello');
     }
 else print('sorry no permission!');
}); 
}
```

any thought! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks Brian and Gunter, I made my own notification, inspired by [this](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html)

I made used the same, CSS file, and made a custom element, notification.dart

```
part of myApp;

class NotificationElement extends HtmlElement {
// Define the custom element tag
static final tag = 'x-Notification';   
factory NotificationElement() => new Element.tag(tag); 
// Create the element and define its stylesheet

NotificationElement.created() : super.created(){
     LinkElement styleSheet = new LinkElement()..rel = "stylesheet"..type="text/css"..href="./style/toastr.css";
      document.head.append(styleSheet);
  }

var notificationContainer = new Element.html('<div></div>')
                          ..id='notification-container';
var notificationBody = new Element.html('<div></div>')
                    ..classes.add('notification');
var notificationButton = new ButtonElement()
                    ..classes.add('notification-close-button')
                    ..text='x';

var notificationTitle = new Element.html('<div></div>')..classes.add('notification-title');
var notificationMsg = new Element.html('<div></div>')..classes.add('notification-message');
var notificationMsgLabel = new LabelElement();

Element launchElement(type,location,Title,Msg){
notificationButton.onClick.listen((e) => notificationContainer.nodes.remove(notificationBody));
notificationContainer..classes.add('notification-'+location);
notificationBody..classes.add('notification-'+type);
notificationTitle.text=Title;
notificationMsg.innerHtml='<label>'+Msg+'</label>';
       notificationBody.nodes..add(notificationButton)..add(notificationTitle)..add(notificationMsg);                        
notificationContainer.nodes..add(notificationBody);
return (notificationContainer);  
}
```

}

```
Element mynotification = querySelector('#notification-element');

void CreatefonixNotification(type,location,Title,Msg){
    var notifyMe = new Element.tag('x-notification');
    notifyMe = notifyMe.launchElement(type,location,Title,Msg);
    mynotification.nodes.add(notifyMe);
}
```

in the index.dart, I registered the element:

```
document.registerElement(NotificationElement.tag, NotificationElement);
```

and in index.html, I added this div:

```
<div id='notification-element'></div>
```

and any place in the application, I can call it like:

```
CreateNotification('error','top-left','Error:','sorry we have some issue!!.')
```

Answer (score 2):

The code as it's currently written would never show a permission either way -- "default" means that permission hasn't been allowed or denied.  You should be checking for `permission == "granted"` before displaying the notification.

Keep in mind, there is an outstanding bug with notifications and checking the current permissions, see https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=20585, although this may not be affecting you.

Comment: whatever I click, it shows the result as "default", so the if (...) will have permission either default or !default

Comment: Are you able to post a more complete example of your code?

Comment: there is nothing special in real, the code I'm trying is just to give a notification once it is run, I little tuned the question statement, thabks

Comment: Huh, that's odd.  Gunter had originally posted an answer saying that the notification needs to be triggered by a user event, which is true.  In my experience working with this, you won't even be asked permission by the browser unless the notification is requesting permission as the result of a user event.  So, if you put that code in the click handler of a button, it should work.